# Packages in java not compile

Tags: java, package, windows-10

Good morning everyone!

I did a project x but all my files were out of order so I decided to group them by folders.

foldera

---ClassA.java

---ClassB.java

folderb

---Class1.java

Main.java

The problem arises when I try to compile, since in the main it appears that the classes I made are not found

I thought this could be solved by putting in the classes

```
 package src.foldera.ClassA;
```

And in the others the same

```
 package src.foldera.ClassB;
```

And

```
 package src.folderb.Class1;
```

So in all classes

And in the main put

```
 import src.foldera.*;
 import src.folderb.*;
```

But I keep getting the same error even though I put the packages

It should be noted that I did not create the folders in the code editor, rather I did it in the same Windows 10 File system

What is this about? Thanks!

Comment: If you want to include `ClassA` in other files, you should do `import src.foldera.ClassA;`. If you want to define the package for `ClassA`, you should do `package src.foldera`.

Comment: Is the "src" package definition correct? Normally this is used to organize source for the build tool and the package is without "src".

And did only I miss the error message?
How do you compile?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a *standard* setup where the `src` folder is the root of your source hierarchy, the statements should be:

```java
package foldera;

package folderb;
```

The imports should be similarly shortened to:

```java
import foldera.*;

import folderb.*;
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to define the package in which the class is in.

As an example in classA:

```
package src.foldera;
```

And in class1:

```
package src.folderb;

import src.foldera.ClassA;
```